# How do I make Ubuntu resume from suspend mode by pressing a key on the keyboard?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sleep, power-management, suspend

In Windows I can get my computer to resume from sleep mode by pressing any key on the keyboard. My keyboard is a Logitech G15 (USB).

How can I get this functionality in Ubuntu?

Comment: I have a dell 1405 with ubuntu, and when it sleeps, I have always found it hard to resume, so i turned off that feature.. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=3066404

Comment: This is probably the most comprehensive answer to the question on the Stack Exchange network: [Wake up from suspend using wireless USB keyboard or mouse (for any Linux Distro)](https://askubuntu.com/q/848698/917895). 10 years after your question, this still seems unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it a USB keyboard? Maybe [this thread at Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=814939) can help.

Comment: Yep, it's a USB keyboard (Logitech G15 to be exact).